# Powershell. Loop through certificate store and remove cert based on thumbprint

Tags: powershell, certificate

I have a simple powershell script that runs via a GPO startup script.
As you can see, it takes a thumbprint an loops through the cert store and removes it if it finds it.

```
#thumbprint of certificate to remove
$thumb = "abcdef444444857694df5e45b68851868"

#loop through all the certs stores looking for $thumb and remove if found
get-childitem Cert:/ -recurse | where-object {$_.thumbprint -contains "$thumb"} | remove-item
```

When I run the above two lines from an elevated powershell prompt **it works**!

If I reboot my machine and let the GPO do it's thing OR if I run from an elevated powershell prompt the below:

```
powershell.exe -Noninteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Noprofile -file "\\mydomain.corp\SysVol\mydomain.corp\Policies\{7086C68E-D509-9169-A02B-56579826C234}\Machine\Scripts\Startup\removecerts.ps1"
```

Then I get the following:

> remove-item : The operation is on user root store and UI is not allowed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try adding the `-Force` parameter to the `Remove-Item` command

Comment: That did it Mathias. I feel like a dumb@$$! Thanks for the help. Really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it's prompting for confirmation, which it can't when running headless.

Adding the `-Force` parameter should override the confirmation prompt:

```
... | Remove-Item -Force
```

Alternatively, set the [`$ConfirmPreference` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables#confirmpreference) to `None` before attempting to remove the certificates to avoid the prompt:

```
$ConfirmPreference = 'None'
<# rest of script goes here #>
```

Comment: I guess I spoke too soon above. Odd behaviour....I added the two changes. The force switch and the ConfirmPreference variable and it worked. Then I reinstalled the cert and tried again and got the same error. You can see the switch in the error also:


remove-item : The operation is on user root store and UI is not allowed.
At \\mydomain.corp\SysVol\mydomain.corp\Policies\{7086C68E-D509-9169-A02B-56579826C234}\Machine\Scripts\Startup\removecerts.ps1:5 char:83
+ ...  where-object {$_.thumbprint -contains "$thumb"} | remove-item -Force

Comment: were you able to get this resolved @Xyz ? thanks in advance!

Comment: @Xyz were either of you able to resolve this? Seems it cant be done programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

script now looks like this:

```
$ConfirmPreference = 'None'

#thumbprint of certificate to remove
$thumb = "abcdef444444857694df5e45b68851868"

#loop through all the certs stores looking for $thumb and remove if found
get-childitem Cert:/ -recurse | where-object {$_.thumbprint -contains "$thumb"} | remove-item -Force
```

And my error:

````
remove-item : The operation is on user root store and UI is not allowed.
At \\mydomain.corp\SysVol\mydomain.corp\Policies\{7086C68E-D509-9169-A02B-56579826C234}\Machine\Scripts\Startup\removecerts.ps1:16 char:88
+ ...  {$_.thumbprint -match "$thumb"} | remove-item -Force
+                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Remove-Item], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

@gfoley83

Sorry, I should have posted way back when, when I finally got this working. So, here is the final script that I use that does what I need it to do. It's run through a windows scheduled task, it's the only way I could get it to work. Hope this helps:

```
do { 
    Write-Host "Waiting for connection"
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5 
} until (Test-Connection 'mydomain.corp' -Quiet -Count 1)
#setup our logging
$ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"
#start powershell in an elevated prompt
start-process powershell -verb runas
#name of scheduled task
$task="internalSoftwarePublisherRootRemoval"
#no confirmations
$ConfirmPreference="none"
#thumbprint of certificate to remove
$thumb = "abcdef444444857694df5e45b68851868"
#Gather our info out of the localmachine trusted root store
$data = get-childitem Cert:\LocalMachine\ -recurse | select-object pspath, thumbprint 
#run through and delete $thumb
Write-host "Searching for and removing our expired certificate."
$data | foreach-object {
            $path = test-path $_.pspath
            if($_.thumbprint -eq "$thumb" -and $path -eq $true){
                remove-item $_.pspath -Confirm:$false
                }
        }
#remove scheduled task
Write-host "Searching for and removing our task."
if (Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName $task){
Unregister-ScheduledTask -TaskName $task -Confirm:$false
}
```